# なんか in 「わたしなんかできませんよ。」

Tags: usage

> A: ぜひ、君にこの仕事をしてもらいたいんだ。
> B: わたし**なんか**できませんよ。この会社に入ったばかりですから。

I learned that なんか expresses that one doesn't appreciate the preceding thing much. In this case, it would be わたし. I could think of contexts where this makes sense, but I feel unsure about what is meant in these sentences. In the following sentence, I think ばかり expresses that the subject just entered the company. In that case, maybe なんか is used because the subject thinks of himself as not sufficiently competent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track with 'I learned that なんか expresses that one doesn't appreciate the preceding thing much.' Basically, なんか here expresses a light form of self-deprecation. It helps 'soften' their refusal to do the work.

> A: 'Please, I'd like you to do this work.'
>
> B: 'There's no way *I* (of all people) could do it. I've only just entered this company, after all.'